# django-channels does not work with daphne on linux server

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels, daphne, asgi

I'm using Django-eventstream over Django channels to send an event to my client app (react using eventstream),
on my local machine the events are sent correctly to the client.
but when I upload the app to my Linux server the webhook just getting open and 'keep-alive' but the events won't get to the client at all.
I use daphne to deploy my Asgi app and use Nginx as my getaway.
when I use **"python manage.py runserver"** (on the Linux server) the client is getting all the messages.
because of that my clients **do** get the messages when I use runserver command I assume that my Nginx configuration is right (correct me if I'm wrong) and the problem is in Daphne somehow.
I don't see the events trying to be sent in the daphne logs at all.
does anyone have a clue why this is happening?
Thanks!

the command I used to run Daphne:

daphne --verbosity 3 -p 8001 my_project.asgi:application

here is my Daphne log:

```
[06/12/2019 14:52:34] INFO [daphne.cli:287] Starting server at tcp:port=8001:interface=127.0.0.1
2019-12-06 14:52:34,376 INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=8001:interface=127.0.0.1
[06/12/2019 14:52:34] INFO [daphne.server:311] HTTP/2 support enabled
2019-12-06 14:52:34,377 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
[06/12/2019 14:52:34] INFO [daphne.server:311] Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8001:interface=127.0.0.1
2019-12-06 14:52:34,377 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8001:interface=127.0.0.1
[06/12/2019 14:52:34] INFO [daphne.server:131] HTTPFactory starting on 8001
2019-12-06 14:52:34,378 INFO     HTTPFactory starting on 8001
[06/12/2019 14:52:34] INFO [daphne.server:131] Starting factory <daphne.http_protocol.HTTPFactory object at 0x7fb1fd600cf8>
2019-12-06 14:52:34,378 INFO     Starting factory <daphne.http_protocol.HTTPFactory object at 0x7fb1fd600cf8>
[06/12/2019 14:52:34] INFO [daphne.server:654] Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8001
2019-12-06 14:52:34,379 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8001
[06/12/2019 14:52:38] DEBUG [daphne.http_protocol:160] HTTP b'GET' request for ['127.0.0.1', 49034]
2019-12-06 14:52:38,215 DEBUG    HTTP b'GET' request for ['127.0.0.1', 49034]
[06/12/2019 14:52:38] DEBUG [daphne.http_protocol:246] HTTP 200 response started for ['127.0.0.1', 49034]
```

Comment: Runserver uses the Channels development server(drop-in ASGI replacement for Django's development server) and not Daphne and definitely not Nginx.

Comment: Ye but the point is that when i use the development server all works well but when i use daphne the client dosent get my messages at all. Im sorry if i wasn't clear on my linux server i use Nginx as gateway, when the nginx pass the call to Daphne the client dosent get the message  at all. But when i run the development server ( and the Nginx pass to call to it) all works well.